# How to modify Rad Studio Community Edition

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

During the setup of Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.2.3 Community Edition I did not select the Interbase Express components. Now I want to install those components, but could not find a way to modify the installation to select those components.

How can I modify a RAD Studio Community Edition installation after the initial setup?

Comment: Use _Tools - Manage Platforms_

Comment: @UweRaabe Tnx mate. Please put answer +1.

Comment: See [Adding or Removing Features Using the Feature Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Adding_or_Removing_Features_Using_the_Feature_Manager) in Embarcadero's documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*RAD Studio* can be installed either from the web installer or from the ISO image. While the ISO installation provides a *Modify* option like any other MSI setup, the web installer uses a different approach.

Installations done with the web installer have an additional menu item in the IDE under *Tools* named *Manage Platforms*, which opens the setup selection dialog already seen during the initial installation. There you can select (and deselect) other platforms and components.

As the *Community Edition* can only be installed with the web installer, everything said about that one also holds true for a Community Edition installation.